# Fiddler makes web browsing very slow

Tags: fiddler

While Fiddler is working perfectly for me, it does seem to make browsing very slow.  Opening this site just took about ten seconds with Fiddler running.  If I close it, it loads pretty much instantly.

I was wondering if this is just how things have to work with Fiddler, or if there is an option or setting I should change to speed things up.

Comment: There's a "streaming" toggle button.  Not sure what it does, but it sounds like it would help :)

Comment: It's been a bit slower for me to.  I think they're just getting more traffic now.

Comment: @imoda... Um... I'm asking about the app, not the website.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't mention what browser you're using. I'm guessing that you're probably using Chrome. Apparently, they have a bug that a few users have reported (which most folks never see). Apparently, the workaround is to disable their "DNS Prefetch" option, which is mislabeled, because the problem has nothing to do with DNS Prefetch (which is disabled behind a proxy anyway).

This is discussed in the Fiddler discussion group.  http://groups.google.com/group/httpfiddler/