# Slow Performance on HTTP PUT Calls via Chrome

Tags: performance, google-chrome, asp.net-web-api, postman, fiddler

I have an ASP.NET Web API that exposes all the verbs - the methods are basically empty.

To run the project, you can do this: spin up a new asp.net web project from VS 2017 - then choose Web API. Once the project is created, do a clean and then rebuild. Open up "ValuesController", put a break point inside the PUT method, and run your project.

Here are the code for the API (controller code - I added a line in PUT method):

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/values
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/values/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    // POST api/values
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // PUT api/values/5
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
    {
        var x = "value: " + value;
    }

    // DELETE api/values/5
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }
}
```

I do not get the same problem or time difference (or they are very negligible) for other HTTP methods (GET, POST, DELETE).

GET timing data:

[image: GET timing data]

POST timing data:

[image: POST timing data]

DELETE timing data:

[image: DELETE timing data]

PUT timing data via **IE**:

[image]

Now - here is PUT timing data via **CHROME**:

[image: PUT timing data]

---

I also have tried putting my API on a server - so calling the API would be a call to http://test-server-01/api/values/1 etc - but the same issue for PUT persist.

**My question: Can anybody explain what is going on? Why is the call for PUT so slow compared to other VERBS? This only happens in Chrome too - I tried making the same calls in IE, resulting in much faster performance.**

---

**[UPDATED]**

I did some timing gathering using Chrome Dev Tools and I noticed that most of th delay are happening on Slow Time to First Byte (TTFB). Here is a screen shot of one of my timing data:

[image]

---

**[UPDATED MORE]**

Here are some more timing data between IE vs Chrome without Fiddler. Timing is captured using respective developer tools.

[image]

[image]

The timing above is pretty much the average of multiple PUT calls in IE and in Chrome. Chrome always ~8 seconds and IE is about ~4 seconds.

As comparison, issuing a POST in IE and Chrome are resulting in negligible difference between them - they all resulting around ~20ms to ~50ms (although Chrome is almost always faster).

Making a DELETE call also similar to POST in result, ranging ~10ms to ~18ms (Chrome is almost always faster).

---

**[UPDATE MORE MORE]**

I tried creating an MCVE - but I cannot duplicate the issue on a different machine. I put the solution on a different laptop, run it using VS 2017, hit localhost via Chrome - no delay/poor performance calling PUT. The timing data that I gathered is on par or similar to POST or DELETE.

So it seems this problem is probably isolated to my work machine. Could it be network issue? Proxy? But if it is the case - should not all calls, including POST or DELETE or GET be delayed or getting poor performance as well? Or why is IE performing better for PUT - if the issue is related to network/proxy?

---

**[UPDATE MORE MORE MORE]**

I ran the PUT call via curl using bash - very fast, no delay whatsoever from the same machine that gave me 8 seconds with CHROME.

[image]

Comment: do multiple calls and take an average, see if there is any change based on the amount of calls.

Comment: Next have all the actions return actual responses `IHttpActionResult` and measure performance again. Could very well be the framework having to interpret the desired response from the actions/endpoints

Comment: @Nikosi - The screen shots are pretty much the average of multiple calls - they are about the same for each Fiddler and Postman with negligible differences between calls. I understand if the first call may take some time, but that is not what we are talking about here.

Comment: @Nikosi - changing the response type also did not any difference - the discrepancy between Fiddler vs Postman is still about the same.

Comment: What happens if the DELETE method also takes a payload? I wonder if there could be something going on with chrome being able preflight the payload differently with GET/POST vs other verbs (not exactly your case but this is relevant in other places: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin)

Comment: Can you also try to disable Nagles algorithm and Delayed Ack on the serverside (this can cause up to 400-600ms increase in latency when the client is expecting an ack from the backend before sending a full payload). It may depend on your framework but at the lowest level here is an example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-US/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.nodelay(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It seems that you make requests via the Fiddler proxy. Please rule out that Fiddler is affecting the measurements due to the proxy connection (and that Fiddler is differently integrated with IE vs. Chrome). Make multiple requests and take the average value (don't rely on the first and only measurement after the page load). To rule out problems in your browser and any influence by addons use for example `curl -w` to take measurements. Is Fiddler involved in the Chrome measurements from your update? Show us the request & response headers of IE and Chrome.

Comment: The timings show your app is taking the same time for IE and Chrome.  It's therefore in the pre-request processing that you're losing the time.  My guess is it's related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500487/fiddler-makes-web-browsing-very-slow.

Comment: @PeterBrittain I don't think it is related to Fiddler at all - since using the app using POSTMAN or other REST calling tool result in the same manner where CHROME is much much slower than IE. I do agree with you that the issue might be in the pre-request. But the thing is why is it only for PUT? Other verbs are just fine and giving similar performance with other browser (IE/Edge)?

Comment: @try-catch-finally Yes - I have ruled out that Fiddler is the culprit - the performance is just as slow using CHROME without Fiddler (using average timing).

Comment: @AnilVaitla Hm - I am not sure that is the issue though. As you can see, there is really nothing complicated about the code here - and this is happening on localhost AND at the server.

Comment: "[...] put a break point inside the PUT method [...]". Do we both understand the same under "break point"? A debugger break point? One that will stop the server process for debugging? One that remains stopped until you step/continue? Please clarify. Apart from this. Make sure you've eliminated Fiddler and all addons from Chrome (in doubt: use a new profile). Create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for both server and client (use minimalist XHR code). Add it to your question along with HAR recordings from Firefox and Chrome. A proper MCVE is better filed as a Chrome bug report.

Comment: @try-catch-finally the breakpoint was just for verifying that the method is actually called. All the timings in the question is done without breakpoint enabled in VS 2017. Yes - your definition of "breakpoint" is right on. Now - having said that, I tried creating an MCVE, but the problem cannot be recreated beyond my work machine. I have tried recreating the problem in several different machines, even an Azure VM - but no delay/poor PUT performance.

Comment: Do you have any kind of Antivirus or a Firewall? I would suggest to disable that too. Also see if you can use Wireshark to check for any anomalies

Comment: @TarunLalwani I think they are disabled - or at least ones I am aware off. Not making any diff whether they are enabled or disabled as far as I know during my testing.

Comment: Can you also try with the chrome developer build which will have the latest dev code?

Comment: @TarunLalwani I cannot do that at this point - what would it accomplish?